# R: Is the assignment order of vector elements indexed by ordinal well defined?

Tags: r

When assigning to a vector by ordinal, is the order of assignment well-defined, or is this implementation dependent? Are there any language specifications regarding this?

```
x <- 1:10
x[c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,3,3)] <- 1:10
```

In the above code, the resultant vector is 2  4 10  8  5  6  7  8  9 10 on my system. Are all R implementations required to assign to each element in order, or are they free to assign in any order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?"[<-"`:

> Subassignment is done sequentially, so if an index is specified more
>   than once the latest assigned value for an index will result.

Therefore the result should be consistent.